# HTML change causes Javascript Unexpected token '!'

Tags: javascript, html

When I do a change do my HTML file no matter what it is, I get a javascript error `Unexpected token '!'`. It seems like I can't do any changes to my HTML file without getting a javascript error. There is nothing wrong with my code.

Comment: Well there's obviously something wrong with it if there is an error - Mind sharing the HTML and JS so we can help?

Comment: The error is caused by an html change.

Comment: Post your code. Simple as that.

Comment: If i just add a new line, the error happens.

Comment: Sounds like an encoding issue - what platform is your server, and what is your editing environment?

Comment: @MikeBrockington .html - local - Visual Studio Code. The error is happening on Chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't set meta charset and that was the error.
`<meta charset="utf-8"/>` in the top of  worked.

Thanks @MikeBrockington